# Best way to traverse Webpack modules tree downwards

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, bundler

I'm working on some Webpack related projects in which I need to analyse the whole modules tree.

Currently I'am traversing upwards, using the `module.reasons` property, which has all the modules that are parents of the current module. However, I can't find the analog property containing child modules.

I'm basing the traversing algorithm on Webpack's `Module` class, because it should be able to perform the recursion on any kind of module. (All module instances of any other class extending `Module`)

While testing, I saw a `module.dependencies` property, but it is not defined in `Module` constructor and I couldn't find how it is populated.

Any idea on how can I traverse downwards? Is there some other property that I'm missing? Or should I access the tree using a different Webpack interface and not directly from inside `Module` instances?

***UPDATE:***

I'm using `module.dependencies` because I've confirmed that somehow it is present on every module. However, it only lists static dependencies (EX: `import {something} from 'some/module.js'`), but not dynamic ones (even if resolvable) like (`import('some/module.js')`). Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further analysing Webpack's source code I have found that `module.blocks` property holds a reference for every parsed 'internal dependency block' (internal declarations and assignments) inside the module, including dynamic `import()` statements.

`module.blocks` is an array of `block` objects. Each block has a `block.dependencies` property which is an array of `dependency` objects.

You are interested in the `dependency` objects which are instances of `ImportDependency`.

Something like this:

```js
function getAllChildModules(module) {
    const childModules = [];

    // GET STATIC CHILD MODULES
    module.dependencies.forEach((dep) => {
        childModules.push(dep.module);
    });

    // GET DYNAMIC CHILD MODULES
    module.blocks.forEach((blk) => {
        blk.dependencies.forEach((dep) => {
            if (dep.constructor.name === 'ImportDependency') {
                childModules.push(dep.module);
            }
        });
    });

    return childModules;
}
```

Confirmation [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10647).

Comment: in what context is this information available on the module? in a loader? In some hook in a plugin?

does this work with webpack v4? or with v5? or both?

Comment: @Reinis it is available for plugins tapping into any [compiler](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/) or [compilation](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-hooks/) hook with access to the dependency tree after modules are built. I've tested this only in `v4`, but should be the same in `v5`. In the module, at runtime, this information is surely not accessible. Same for loaders.

Comment: if this information is not available in a loader, how do you go about modifying the source code of a module based on this information you've collected?